# What does Ajax's header do

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

What is Ajax's header's role? Why do we need this?

And in this specific case below, what cause the differences between with `xhttp.setRequestHeader()` and without?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
}
xhttp.open("POST", "demo_post2.asp", true);
// xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it send the information like 'type of data' to your server so that server can handle it corrrectly

Comment: You are likely to get downvoted for such question here.Request Headers informs server about the generated requests.In your case it wont make a difference if you if you comment that line as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the default.just an example try reading about CORS

Comment: But actually without it the log shows `<p>Hello</p>`, and with it the log shows `<p>Hello Henry Ford</p>`. That's where it really confused me, is there anything about the specific asp that cause this?

Comment: It makes a difference here. I assume it has related to `"Content-type"`.

Comment: @David `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;` is the default one dont know why it is not in this case,this encoding changes the `&` sign to `&amp;` while processing and this is the cause of difference you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP headers are used to send additional data, or metadata, along with the main body of the request to provide information, such as the content-type, to either the server or the browser; for example, the browser may tell the server that it expects the server to respond with JSON encoded data.

In this case, setting the `content-type` to `x-www-form-urlencoded` tells the server that form data encoded as a URL query-string (e.g. using `?name=value&othername=othervalue`). If you wanted to upload a file instead of sending regular form data, you would use `multipart/form-data` as the `content-type` instead